# export highchart to image arabic text

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

am trying to export highchart to image, my high chart contains arabic labels (captions) after export arabic text shows as question marks, i tried to add (useHTML) and changed the script encoding to (utf8) and it still showing as question marks.

```
 var options = {
            chart: {
                style: {
                    fontFamily: 'arial'
                },
                height: 300,
                events: {
                    drilldown: function (e) {
                        generateDrillDownJSON(e, false);
                    },
                    drillup: function (e) {
                        generateDrillDownJSON(e, true);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: Var_ChartTitleText,
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: Var_ChartSubtitleText,
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.point.name + ' : ' + this.y + ' %';
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: true
            },
            drilldown: Var_drilldown,
            legend: {
                enabled: true

            },
            plotOptions: {
                allowhtml: true,
                series: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        formatter: function () {
                            return this.point.name + ' : ' + this.y + ' %';
                        }
                    },
                    useHTML: true,
                    shadow: true
                },
                pie: {
                    size: '100%',
                    showInLegend: true
                }
            },

            series: Var_Series
        };
```

when exporting it shows as below
[image]

Comment: Can you post a working demo?

Comment: Looks like all examples here are working fine. https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/internationalization

Comment: If you can post a working demo, someone can help you out even better

Comment: the dashboard data are fine in arabic, but the issue appears when export it to image

Comment: Can u throw a demo in codepen?